# Create Windows 10 Backup TimeMachine like

Tags: windows-10, time-machine, windows-backup

Is it possible to create a Backup with Windows 10 that behaves like Apple's Time Machine Backup system?

I know Windows 10 has some new Backup features but I am not familiar with them. I usually use Apple and had excellent experience with Time Machine which enables me to recover your Data from each time. And creates Backup on every change I make.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can with commercial software [Arq](https://www.arqbackup.com). Its author started with a version for Mac and later released one for Windows.
Check the standalone version (not cloud backup).

Arq combines:

- git-style versioning - large files are split and stored in blocks identified and referenced by their checksums making them immutable and providing natural deduplication.
- Time Machine-like schedule and garbage collection. Specifically storing frequent backups (1 hour by default) and periodically removing them; leaving first: weekly backups and finally: monthly backups kept forever, or until cleaned if you configured space-restrictions.
- all data is encrypted at source with AES.

If you want to store files locally, you can connect to your own storage/server with SFTP.

One important factor: although the software is proprietary, the author publishes the [restore algorithms on github](https://github.com/sreitshamer/arq_restore). Unfortunately the source files have not beed updated to the latest version, but there is another GitHub project [arqinator](https://github.com/asimihsan/arqinator) updated recently and claimed to be tested across all platforms.

---

Disclaimer: I'm a licensed user of Arq (not involved otherwise). I was attracted by its technical model (git-like features) and not so happy at first with little control over storage options (the Time Machine part), but after a few restores, I came to appreciate its simplicity.

Comment: This a proper software recommendation, you provide how the software works, and provide a reason other than "it will solve the problem"